# Unir dataframes por columna con filas parecidas en R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando crear un dataframe en base a dos que tengo pero me he encontrado con un problema. Ambos tienen una columna llamada NOmbre, en el que aparecen los nombres de los jugadores de fútbol en España, pero por ejemplo en unmo aparece "Lionel Messi" y en el otro solo "Messi".

Hay alguna manera de juntar los dataframes por esa columna con los nombres parecidos?

Gracias.

Acabo de "solucionarlo" con esta función:

```
    for (i in 1:min(length(data$Nombre), length(data_j$Nombre))){
  ind <- which(grepl(data_j$Nombre[i], data$Nombre))
  if (length(ind)==0){
    data_j$Nombre[i] = data_j$Nombre[i]
    print(data_j$Nombre)
  }
  else{
  data_j$Nombre[i] = data$Nombre[ind]
  }
}
```

Pero no sé si hay un método más fácil y/o corto.

Answer (score 4):

Tu código tienen un problema, va a fallar si se encuentra más de una coincidencia. Supongamos un jugador como `Roberto Carlos`, dónde en uno de los `dataframe` lo tendrás como `Carlos`, una cadena que sin duda va a coincidir con cualquier nombre `Carlos`. Una mejora que se le puede hacer a tu código, es quedarnos con una sola de las coincidencias `data$Nombre[ind[1]]`, por lo menos no fallará, pero de todas formas el resultado puede que no sea el esperado:

```
data <- data.frame(Nombre=c('Leonel Messi', 'Carlos Tevez', 'Roberto Carlos'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data_j <- data.frame(Nombre=c('Tevez', 'Messi', 'Carlos'), Nuevo=NA, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:min(length(data$Nombre), length(data_j$Nombre))){
    ind <- which(grepl(data_j$Nombre[i], data$Nombre))
    if (length(ind) > 0){
        data_j$Nuevo[i] = data$Nombre[ind[1]]
    }
}

data_j

  Nombre        Nuevo
1  Tevez Carlos Tevez
2  Messi Leonel Messi
3 Carlos Carlos Tevez
```

Puedes ver que de acuerdo al orden, `Carlos` termina coincidiendocon `Carlos Tevez`, que no es lo que se esperaría.

Una solución más práctica es usar `fuzzyjoin` para hacer un `join` difuso entre los dos `dataframes`, la ventaja de esto es que no pierdes coincidencias "ambiguas", y podrías en una segunda etapa, depurar visualmente y dejar solo las coincidencias indicadas.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

data %>% 
    regex_left_join(data_j, by = c(Nombre = "Nombre")) %>%
    select(Nombre = Nombre.y, Nuevo = Nombre.x)

  Nombre          Nuevo
1  Messi   Leonel Messi
2  Tevez   Carlos Tevez
3 Carlos   Carlos Tevez
4 Carlos Roberto Carlos
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Opto por tu método, ya que me había estado peleando después de escribir la pregunta y conseguí crear un dataframe con los nombres y filas de los jugadores que tenían más de una coincidencia, por lo que iba a ir modificando mano a mano el nombre. Muchas gracias!