# Unir dos dataframes por la similitud de caracteres de dos variables con R

Tags: r

Sería posible unir dos dataframes donde en cada uno de ellos hay una variable municipio pero están escritas de forma distinta, con variaciones de acentos, mayúsculas, minúsculas o guiones.

```
c("Abanilla", "Abarán", "Águilas", "Albudeite", "Alcantarilla", 
"Aledo", "Alguazas", "Alhama de Murcia", "Archena", "Beniel", 
"Blanca", "Bullas", "Calasparra", "Campos del Río", "Caravaca de la Cruz", 
"Cartagena", "Cehegín", "Ceutí", "Cieza", "Fortuna", "Fuente Álamo de Murcia", 
"Jumilla", "Librilla", "Lorca", "Lorquí", "Mazarrón", "Molina de Segura", 
"Moratalla", "Mula", "Murcia", "Ojós", "Pliego", "Puerto Lumbreras", 
"Ricote", "San Javier", "San Pedro del Pinatar", "Torre-Pacheco", 
"Las Torres de Cotillas", "Totana", "Ulea", "La Unión", "Villanueva del Río Segura", 
"Yecla", "Santomera", "Los Alcázares")
```

```
c("ABANILLA", "ABARAN", "AGUILAS", "ALCANTARILLA", "ALGUAZAS", 
"ALHAMA DE MURCIA", "ARCHENA", "BENIEL", "BLANCA", "BULLAS", 
"CALASPARRA", "CARAVACA DE LA CRUZ", "CARTAGENA", "CEHEGIN", 
"CEUTI", "CIEZA", "FORTUNA", "FUENTE ÁLAMO", "JUMILLA", "LA UNION", 
"LAS TORRES DE COTILLAS", "LIBRILLA", "LORCA", "LORQUI", "LOS ALCAZARES", 
"MAZARRON", "MOLINA DE SEGURA", "MORATALLA", "MULA", "MURCIA", 
"PLIEGO", "PUERTO LUMBRERAS", "SAN JAVIER", "SAN PEDRO DEL PINATAR", 
"SANTOMERA", "TORRE PACHECO", "TOTANA", "VILLANUEVA DEL RÍO SEGURA", 
"YECLA")
```

He probado la solución propuesta en [Unir dataframes por columna con filas parecidas en R](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241196/unir-dataframes-por-columna-con-filas-parecidas-en-r) utilizando el package `fuzzyjoin` pero no obtengo ningún resultado en este caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posiblemente puedas evitar el uso de un `join` "difuso" si normalizas las columnas aplicando estos criterios:

- Minúsculas
- Quitar acentos
- Reemplazar guiones por espacios

Por ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(municipio = tolower(municipio),
         municipio = stri_trans_general(municipio, id = "Latin-ASCII"),
         municipio = sub('[-]',' ',municipio)
  ) %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>%   
              mutate(municipio = tolower(municipio),
                     municipio = stri_trans_general(municipio, id = "Latin-ASCII"),
                     municipio = sub('[-]',' ',municipio)
                     ),
            by="municipio")
```

Sin embargo con `fuzzyjoin` también podrías hacer algo así:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 %>% 
  stringdist_left_join(df2,
                       by="municipio", 
                       max_dist = 1,
                       ignore_case =TRUE) 

                 municipio.x               municipio.y
1                   Abanilla                  ABANILLA
2                     Abarán                    ABARAN
3                    Águilas                   AGUILAS
4                  Albudeite                      <NA>
5               Alcantarilla              ALCANTARILLA
6                      Aledo                      <NA>
7                   Alguazas                  ALGUAZAS
8           Alhama de Murcia          ALHAMA DE MURCIA
9                    Archena                   ARCHENA
10                    Beniel                    BENIEL
11                    Blanca                    BLANCA
12                    Bullas                    BULLAS
13                Calasparra                CALASPARRA
14            Campos del Río                      <NA>
15       Caravaca de la Cruz       CARAVACA DE LA CRUZ
16                 Cartagena                 CARTAGENA
17                   Cehegín                   CEHEGIN
18                     Ceutí                     CEUTI
19                     Cieza                     CIEZA
20                   Fortuna                   FORTUNA
21    Fuente Álamo de Murcia                      <NA>
22                   Jumilla                   JUMILLA
23                  Librilla                  LIBRILLA
24                     Lorca                     LORCA
25                    Lorquí                    LORQUI
26                  Mazarrón                  MAZARRON
27          Molina de Segura          MOLINA DE SEGURA
28                 Moratalla                 MORATALLA
29                      Mula                      MULA
30                    Murcia                    MURCIA
31                      Ojós                      <NA>
32                    Pliego                    PLIEGO
33          Puerto Lumbreras          PUERTO LUMBRERAS
34                    Ricote                      <NA>
35                San Javier                SAN JAVIER
36     San Pedro del Pinatar     SAN PEDRO DEL PINATAR
37             Torre-Pacheco             TORRE PACHECO
38    Las Torres de Cotillas    LAS TORRES DE COTILLAS
39                    Totana                    TOTANA
40                      Ulea                      <NA>
41                  La Unión                  LA UNION
42 Villanueva del Río Segura VILLANUEVA DEL RÍO SEGURA
43                     Yecla                     YECLA
44                 Santomera                 SANTOMERA
45             Los Alcázares             LOS ALCAZARES
```

`stringdist_left_join` tiene varios métodos, pero todos trabajan con la idea de calcular una distancia entre las dos cadenas, cuanto más chica sea esa distancia, posiblemente se trate de la misma cadena, el parámetro `max_dist` define el umbral.

Comment: Al aplicar ```stringdist_left_join``` con ```max_dist = 1``` observo que no ha encontrado coincidencia entre "Fuente Álamo de Murcia" y "FUENTE ÁLAMO". Al probar con ```max_dist = 2``` entonces "MULA" lo ha unido a "Mula" y "Ulea" produciendo una duplicidad y sigue sin detectar coincidencia entre "Fuente Álamo de Murcia" y "FUENTE ÁLAMO".

Comment: Lo probé con tu ejemplo, y con `max_dist=1` ya funciona muy bien, agrego los resultados que consigo a la respuesta así lo verificas.

Comment: Sí, excepto lo que he comentado. no ha encontrado coincidencia entre "Fuente Álamo de Murcia" y "FUENTE ÁLAMO". Sin duda es una gran avance aunque hay que utilizarlo con precaución.

Comment: Ok, te entiendo,  pero ese caso puntual, me parece que no hay forma de resolverlo. Puedes aumentar `max_dist` pero ciertamente aumentara las coincidencias entre los otros municipios. Si eventualmente estos casos, dónde hay directamente palabras más o menos, no fueran muchos, podrías crear una tabla de alias.

Comment: Para el ejemplo que nos ocupa, he revisado, con los mismos valores para el resto de parámetros, todos los métodos. Los métodos "osa" "lv" "dl" "hamming" producen el mismo resultado que el método por defecto, cuando no indicamos ninguno. Los métodos "lcs" y "qgram" encuentran un menor número de coincidencias. Y los métodos "cosine", "jaccard" y "jw" no ofrecen resultados satisfactorios.